# Analyzing commands in android speech recognition results

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i have a speech recognition app in android and i want to compare the results that i get with my own strings
this is my code

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {

            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            for(String resultString: matches)
            {

            if(resultString.equalsIgnoreCase("go"))
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else if(resultString.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else if(resultString.equalsIgnoreCase("back"))
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else if(resultString.equalsIgnoreCase("right"))
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else if(resultString.equalsIgnoreCase("left"))
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "wrong command use go , stop , back , right or left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


            }
        }
```

i have also tried using `matches.contains("go");`
even that doesnt seem to work. please help me

Comment: what's `resultString` look like in the debugger? might need to `trim()` it.

Comment: can u see this Toast **wrong command use go , stop , back , right or left**

Comment: Are you using correct context (maybe getContext, or getApplicationContext would be better)? You didn't really say what is the problem. Are Toast not showing, or are you getting an exception..? Do you "matches" yield any values at all ?

Answer (score 1):

The results are space separated `String`s, so you have to split your `resultString`

Use a loop like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            List<String> heard = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            Set<String> matchThese = new HashSet<String>();
            matchThese.add("tree");
            matchThese.add("car");

            for (String said : heard)
            {
                String[] saidWords = said.split("\\s");
                for (String wordSaid : saidWords)
                {
                    if (matchThese.contains(wordSaid))
                    {
                        tts.speak("You said the correct word",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet use the tools within [GAST](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib), an open source project which has some speech recognition tools.

Specifically, you at least need [WordMatcher](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text/match/WordMatcher.java) and [WordList](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text/WordList.java)