# Android Speech recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

I am trying to create an app that simply detects specific phrases that the user can speak into the device and the activity will do something depending on what the user has spoken. I had a hard time finding tutorials on this specific thing so please help me out. So far I have created a button that will start the Recognizer Intent and I have a onActivityResult which I hope can detect what the user is saying and then call specific functions depending on the phrase the user has spoken.

```
public void OnClick_Speed_Detector(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "speak up");
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
       //if user says the phrase "poptarts"
       //call function poptart

      //if user says the phrase "banana"
      //call function banana

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sound detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the question then?

Comment: the question is how do i detected when certain phrases are said...

Comment: like if the user says poptarts, how do i code it so the app can react to the phrase "poptarts" and not some other word?

Comment: So would you mind to update the question with the actual question? Currently it is not very clear what are you asking.

Comment: You can find the code to run the analysis of the recognition string here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655162/android-speech-recognition-results-comparing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android specific words speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209343/android-specific-words-speech-recognition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, it's how your code should be to work:

```
 public void OnClick_Speed_Detector(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "speak up");
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //if user says the phrase "poptarts"
        //call function poptart

        //if user says the phrase "banana"
        //call function banana
        ArrayList < String > result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        ArrayList < String > result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


        if (((result).equals(t1))) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, * * ClassToOpen * * .class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (((result).equals(t2))) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, * * ClassToOpen * * .class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sound detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

Put the desired string as **t1** and **t2**.

Hope this helps, vote up or accept if it did.

Comment: Hello, I tried to test this out by changing the intents with toasts instead to display a notification if the word I said is indeed being recognized but it is not working properly. Heres an image of whats been written http://i.imgur.com/xOqoFxV.png

Comment: ohk can u post ur whole code of the ***.java so that i cn find the error u r going with... :) @ssj3goku878

Comment: I dont really have much else code, heres pretty much what I did with your code but I am not getting any results. http://i.imgur.com/2IKLQNP.png I press the button to activate the voice recognizer and I say the word I have entered into the code but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you should use it. It is not like other activities. You haven't even created SpeechRecognizer. Please refer to [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) documentation and see **createSpeechRecognizer()** method. You will also see different kinds of result for this activity. For instance onError() onResults() onEndOfSpeech() etc. You should see an example first. I am sorry I couldn't give you an answer that solves your problem, but your problem is that you are on the wrong way.