# Android specific words speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, recognizer-intent

I am trying to have the app recognize certain words said by the user using the code below, but for some reason it isn't working at all. Please review this and tell me what is wrong with it. Thank you

The app is simply suppose to display a toast message if the words "orange" or "apple" is said but nothing happens when using the code below.

//button onclick to trigger RecognizerIntent

```
public void OnClick_Speed_Detector(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "speak up");
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> result = 
                data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if(((result).equals("orange")))
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "orange", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }   
                else
                    if (((result).equals("apple")))
                { 
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "apple", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, can you tell us if you're receiving the intent result?  That is, put a logging statement at the top of `onActivityResult` and also before `startActivityForResult`.  Is the speech recognizer activity appearing at all?

Comment: Oh duh, I see the problem.  Your result variable is an arraylist, but you're comparing it to strings.  You want to compare it's elements to strings, or use it's `contains` method.  Try logging result.toString() (debugging with Toast is the android equivalent of JavaScript alert debugging, use logging and breakpoints),

Comment: I did a debug of the variable "result" and I said the word "orange" and I got an array of "orange", "Orange"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208081/android-speech-recognition)

Comment: no matter what word I say, the results will always spit out an array of different words that also contain the exact word I have said. Is this because its having trouble figuring out what im saying? Im not even sure what to do here lol

Comment: It's having trouble recognizing what you're saying. The best thing to do here if you're looking for a particular set of words or a grammar would be to build them as described in the android docs, and then deal with the situation when it can't figure out exactly what you're saying.  This will also make your app easier to translate to other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are testing if an ArrayList == a String, when it can't possibly (an ArrayList of type String contains multiple strings)

Instead of:

```
if ((result).equals("orange")) {}
```

Try:

```
if ((result).contains("orange")) {}
```

This code will look through every index of the ArrayList and determine if any of the indexes of it equal "orange". If any do then it will return

```
true
```

...and it will execute the if statement!
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```java
String word1= "orange";
String encoded1 = Soundex.US_ENGLISH.encode(name1); 
String word2= user's spoken word;
String encoded2 = Soundex.US_ENGLISH.encode(name2); 


encoded1.equals(encoded2)

// OR for loose matching...
encoded1.contains(encoded2) || encoded2.contains(encoded1)
```

This matches similar sounding words

for better matching you can use Metaphone3 algorithm. You just need to get the code snippet from internet or write yourself (most probably you won't).
By using metaphone3 you will get below matchings
'by' == 'bye'
"john's" == 'john'
'(./cow' == 'cow'
'y' == 'why'